# Core Dump occured while getting a connection from pool

Tags: java, sqlite, weblogic, datasource, coredump

We have an web app running on WebLogic 12c and Red Hat OS that access a single SQLite database file. For this database, we configured a connection pool, using com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource. When doing non-specific stuff on the client side of the web app, suddenlly WebLogic crashes and a core dump file is generated by the JVM.

Doing some research, I guess it can be something about SQLite using native libraries and try to load them and then the error occurs. This can be seen on the log file generated by the JVM.

```
Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V+0
j  java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/io/File;)Z+328
j  java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;Z)V+48
j  java.lang.Runtime.load0(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)V+57
j  java.lang.System.load(Ljava/lang/String;)V+7
j  org.sqlite.SQLiteJDBCLoader.loadNativeLibrary(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Z+29
j  org.sqlite.SQLiteJDBCLoader.extractAndLoadLibraryFile(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Z+308
j  org.sqlite.SQLiteJDBCLoader.loadSQLiteNativeLibrary()V+224
j  org.sqlite.SQLiteJDBCLoader.initialize()Z+0
j  org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.load()Z+19
j  org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.open(II)V+355
j  org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Properties;)V+138
j  org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Properties;)V+4
j  org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Connection.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Properties;)V+4
j  org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Properties;)V+4
j  org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Properties;)Ljava/sql/Connection;+24
j  org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Properties;)Ljava/sql/Connection;+2
j  com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/sql/Connection;+18
j  com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/mchange/v2/c3p0/ConnectionCustomizer;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/sql/PooledConnection;+25
j  com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/sql/PooledConnection;+5
j  com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource()Ljava/lang/Object;+50
j  com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(I)V+25
j  com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess()V+2
j  com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(Lcom/mchange/v2/resourcepool/BasicResourcePool;)V+1
j  com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run()V+18
j  com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run()V+138
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

I guess this can be helpful too:

```
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fc88369fb32, pid=15075, tid=0x00007fc6679ff700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_92-b31) (build 1.8.0_92-b31)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.92-b31 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+0x18b32]  strcmp+0x2
```

Here is the thread specified on the log file:

```
Current thread (0x00007fc6240f5000):  JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqyqw79hrvpgj518gc0n4|4f77bcba]-HelperThread-#0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=47441, stack(0x00007fc6678ff000,0x00007fc667a00000)]

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x0000000000064a8b
```

I am not sure if this is the problem and if it is, I don know how to fix it. Any ideas of what can be causing this?

Also, we are using JDK 1.8.0-77 and these dependencies on pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.11.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Report this bug at bugs.Java.com

Comment: I'm not sure if this a JDK bug. This is on the log file "The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code."

Comment: I agree about being a JVM issue. Maybe it is related to native library, but still for the JVM for that platform